# How to add uiStepper to uitableviewcell?

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uistepper

In my app I have custom UITableViewCell, and I have UIStepper and UILabel in the custom cell. I don't know how to check which stepper was clicked. So is it a way to know from which cell stepper was clicked? I use swift 3.

I tried this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
let data = ["111111", "2222222","3333333"]

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
return(data.count)
}
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.lb1.text = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.stepper.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperA(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    return (cell)

}
func stepperA (sender: UIStepper){


    print("stepper \(sender.tag) clicked. Its value \(sender.value)")
}











override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tags. Here is an example `cellForRowAt` and your stepper action function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: StepperTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! StepperTableViewCell

    //stepper is your UIStepper reference from StepperTableViewCell
    cell.stepper.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperAction(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    return cell
}
func stepperAction(sender: UIStepper)  {
    print("Stepper \(sender.tag) clicked. Its value \(sender.value)")
}
```

And Its output

```
Stepper 0 clicked. Its value 1.0
Stepper 1 clicked. Its value 1.0
Stepper 0 clicked. Its value 2.0
Stepper 0 clicked. Its value 3.0
Stepper 3 clicked. Its value 1.0
```

Comment: thank you, I'm new in swift and I added my code to my qustion but its not working

Comment: The app shutting down when I click on Stepper, can you make a simple app and give me it opensource so I can check where is my wrong